# Group By combination of month and year together to obtain counts for every month-year combination in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way of getting counts grouped by a combination of month and year together?
Not like group by month, year but group by month_year_combined.
Trying to get counts grouped by month_year as one entity in Snowflake SQL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that month and year are separate columns and both are numeric, one way to get the results would be:

```
WITH SOMEDATA (ID, MONTH, YEAR, QUANTITY) AS
( SELECT * FROM VALUES
(1,7,2022,53)
,(2,4,2022,64)
,(3,2,2022,67)
,(4,9,2022,57)
,(5,2,2022,65)
,(6,5,2022,85)
,(7,11,2022,31)
,(8,11,2022,66)
,(9,6,2022,35)
,(10,1,2022,51)
,(11,7,2022,67)
,(12,5,2022,57)
,(13,3,2022,73)
,(14,12,2022,63)
,(15,11,2022,28)
,(16,9,2022,51)
)
SELECT 100*YEAR+MONTH AS YEAR_MONTH, SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_QUANTITY
FROM SOMEDATA
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| YEAR_MONTH | SUM_QUANTITY |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 51 |
| 202202 | 132 |
| 202203 | 73 |
| 202204 | 64 |
| 202205 | 142 |
| 202206 | 35 |
| 202207 | 120 |
| 202209 | 108 |
| 202211 | 125 |
| 202212 | 63 |